# HTML 5 Canvas vs Divs for scrolling pane

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making an TV Guide. See http://i.tv/guide for an example implementation using Canvas.

I need to make lots of little boxes representing each show. I need to be able to scroll them around, both vertically (channels) and horizontally (time). To make it with Canvas, my understanding is that the only way to implement scrolling is to intercept the correct events, and redraw the canvas smoothly with new offsets many times a second.

If I were to use divs, I could slap scrollbars on it and let it scroll normally. I could position them once, and let the scrolling move them around, rather than re-calculating their new offsets.

Which should I pick for this kind of project? If I use divs will it be too slow? Some lineups have 500 channels. I want to display up to 4 hours at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using plain HTML in preference to canvas, for interactive elements. Apart from the speed issue (divs are usually going to be faster than drawing it all manually yourself), HTML is designed to offer accessibility and usability features for free, which you'd have to do a lot of work to get even partially from canvas.

The canvas-based guide as linked has the following drawbacks:

- very slow to render/scroll, for me;
- impervious to keyboard navigation;
- no HTML link actions (like middle-click-link-to-open-in-new-tab or right-click-bookmark);
- text not copy/pastable;
- a dead loss for accessibility tools like screen-readers;
- reduced browser compatibility;
- invisible to search engines.

Use canvas for pretty graphical and interactive effects you can't achieve with plain HTML. To be honest I don't even see any of that on i.tv's site; I have no idea why they have implemented it in this seemingly-crazy way.

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with DIV's wont have issues with speed. Browsers rendering engines are built to render elements. DOM rendering is faster than canvas rendering in a lot of cases, take [isogenicengine](http://www.isogenicengine.com/) they use DOM based rendering to render thousands of elements to make games You should implement it based on your technical ability. Both technologies will be able to do what you want. Personally I would choose canvas but I see no issue with DOM rendering.

Good Luck.

Comment: Actually Isogenic Engine uses canvas for all the videos and demos we produce. DOM rendering is an option but for the most part, our canvas renderer is fast enough to handle loads and loads of entities on screen at once!

Canvas is not slow unless you have lots of moving elements and don't optimise your render process, DOM rendering allows you to render fast without much effort though... there is nothing wrong with DOM rendering!

Comment: This was a while ago, back then I believe that the demo videos I saw was using DOM based rendering. Either way its a great looking engine!